# Nested xsl templates to extract complex element paths from XML

Tags: xml, xslt, nested-loops

I’m using a mind mapping application called iThoughts to build a terminology/ontology. The application uses text nodes that can have children connected by edges. iThoughts can output to xml. A slightly cleaned up version looks like this …

```
<node ID="0659C319-781F-425B-B5C4-A58D9703058E" TEXT="A" STYLE="bubble" FOLDED="false" CREATED="1506338610407" MODIFIED="1506338655247">
<node ID="2FFA8D7E-31FC-4BDD-9237-03306E000E69" TEXT="A A" STYLE="bubble" FOLDED="false" POSITION="right" CREATED="1506338626015" MODIFIED="1506451463949">
    <node ID="8CDBBE54-01FD-43E2-9E8C-FCEF05C939D0" TEXT="A A A" STYLE="bubble" FOLDED="false" CREATED="1506338633301" MODIFIED="1506451469473">
    </node>
</node>
<node ID="F90EDE7F-1D1E-416E-B06D-C3DB272908C0" TEXT="A B" STYLE="bubble" FOLDED="false" POSITION="right" CREATED="1506338639646" MODIFIED="1506451486753">
    <node ID="AEED653C-6EB9-4B04-8E74-B054EE2DFC4B" TEXT="A B A" STYLE="bubble" FOLDED="false" CREATED="1506338687585" MODIFIED="1506451473365">
    </node>
    <node ID="DD8AAAEF-EEB7-4DA0-AE69-DABB68617AB6" TEXT="A B B" STYLE="bubble" FOLDED="false" CREATED="1506338694145" MODIFIED="1506451477067">
        <arrowlink DESTINATION="6377D5CA-5E48-42C1-8ECB-8B15D7E0DC65" COLOR="#FFB2B2" STARTARROW="None" ENDARROW="Default" SOURCE_LABEL="" MIDDLE_LABEL="" TARGET_LABEL=""/>
        <node ID="B31AD99B-40D1-4A72-8EB6-8EBBD7100F28" TEXT="A B B A" STYLE="bubble" FOLDED="false" CREATED="1506451516240" MODIFIED="1506451522888">
        </node>
    </node>
    <node ID="45D5FBFB-2FF2-4220-A0EB-6623891404AB" TEXT="1 2" STYLE="bubble" FOLDED="false" CREATED="1506451492888" MODIFIED="1506451497507">
        <attribute NAME="Callout" VALUE="{-151, 114}"/>
    </node>
</node>
<node ID="6377D5CA-5E48-42C1-8ECB-8B15D7E0DC65" TEXT="A C" STYLE="bubble" FOLDED="false" POSITION="right" CREATED="1506339141624" MODIFIED="1506451488789">
</node>
</node>
```

… which defines a top node Called “A” that has children “A A”, “A B” and “A C”. “A A” has one child “A A A”, etc.

In addition, one can add a link between any 2 nodes. These links are defined by  elements. In the above example I have defined a link between “A B B” and “A C” … the link starts from “A B B” since it is within that node’s xml and the link ends on “A C” which is encoded by the DESTINATION attribute of the arrowlink being equal to the target node’s ID. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dQBy.png)

Note that one of the nodes has a child of type attribute with a NAME=“Callout”. I am using these “callout” nodes to represent synonyms. So the default concept called “A B” has a synonym called “1 2”.

I am trying to use xml transform to generate lists of genre expanded synonyms for ElasticSearch (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/synonyms-expand-or-contract.html#synonyms-genres). So I want the following …

```
A => A
A A => A_A, A 
A A A => A_A_A, A_A, A
A B, 1 2 => A_B, A
A B A => A_B_A, A_B, A
A B B => A_B_B, A_B, A_C, A
A B B A => A_B_B_A, A_B_B, A_B, A_C, A
A C => A_C, A
```

Most of this is just the path of a node and I have this working fine. But the arrowlink nodes and the callout nodes have me vexed. This is what I have so far …

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="text"/> 
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="node[not (attribute)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@TEXT, ' => ')"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::node[not (attribute)]">
        <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(string-join( tokenize(@TEXT, '\s'), '_'), ', ')"/>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From within the for-each loop, how do I determine if there is an arrowlink and if there is, find the target node and then setup another  with another  to continue up the chain from the target of this arrowlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to follow cross-references you can define a key e.g. `<xsl:key name="id" match="node" use="@ID"/>` and then you can inside a template or for-each with a `node` element as the context node use `key('id', arrowlink/@DESTINATION)` to find/select all referenced destination nodes.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. But now I have some nodes listed multiple times when a node's path and a cross-reference's path join towards the top of the hierarchy. Any idea how I can check for duplicates before adding a node to the output?

Answer (score 0):

I used Martin's `key('id', arrowlink/@DESTINATION)` suggestion (thanks) and came up with the following ...

Here is a slightly more complex xml with multiple cross-references including multilevel cross-reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<map version="0.9.0">
    <node ID="0659C319-781F-425B-B5C4-A58D9703058E" TEXT="A">
        <node ID="2FFA8D7E-31FC-4BDD-9237-03306E000E69" TEXT="A A">
            <node ID="8CDBBE54-01FD-43E2-9E8C-FCEF05C939D0" TEXT="A A A">
                <arrowlink DESTINATION="1DC44430-AD4A-4EDF-938E-85DE5BC4CA5C" />
            </node>
        </node>
        <node ID="F90EDE7F-1D1E-416E-B06D-C3DB272908C0" TEXT="A B" >
            <node ID="AEED653C-6EB9-4B04-8E74-B054EE2DFC4B" TEXT="A B A" >
            </node>
            <node ID="DD8AAAEF-EEB7-4DA0-AE69-DABB68617AB6" TEXT="A B B" >
                <node ID="B31AD99B-40D1-4A72-8EB6-8EBBD7100F28" TEXT="A B B A" >
                    <arrowlink DESTINATION="42ACB35A-1DA7-4C79-BA40-2D4636C9C7DE" />
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
        <node ID="6377D5CA-5E48-42C1-8ECB-8B15D7E0DC65" TEXT="A C" >
            <node ID="42ACB35A-1DA7-4C79-BA40-2D4636C9C7DE" TEXT="A C A" >
                <arrowlink DESTINATION="1DC44430-AD4A-4EDF-938E-85DE5BC4CA5C" />
            </node>
        </node>
        <node ID="1DC44430-AD4A-4EDF-938E-85DE5BC4CA5C" TEXT="A D" >
        </node>
    </node>
</map>
```

[And here is what it looks like visually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7riw.png)

And here is the xslt ...

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="one"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node[not (attribute)]" mode="one">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@TEXT, ' => ')"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::node[not (attribute)]">
            <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(string-join( tokenize(@TEXT, '\s'), '_'), ', ')"/>

            <xsl:if test="./arrowlink">     
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('id', arrowlink/@DESTINATION)" mode="two"/>        
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 

        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="one"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node[not (attribute)]" mode="two">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::node[not (attribute)]">
            <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(string-join( tokenize(@TEXT, '\s'), '_'), ', ')"/>

            <xsl:if test="./arrowlink">     
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('id', arrowlink/@DESTINATION)" mode="two"/>        
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the output ...

```
A => A, 
A A => A_A, A, 
A A A => A_A_A, A_D, A, A_A, A, 
A B => A_B, A, 
A B A => A_B_A, A_B, A, 
A B B => A_B_B, A_B, A, 
A B B A => A_B_B_A, A_C_A, A_D, A, A_C, A, A_B_B, A_B, A, 
A C => A_C, A, 
A C A => A_C_A, A_D, A, A_C, A, 
A D => A_D, A,
```